# Extract subtring using regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

Hello I have this string and I need extract from this some sub strings according some delimiters:

```
string = """
1538 a
123
skua456
789
5
g
15563 blu55g
b
456
16453 a
789
5
16524 blu
g
55
1734 a
987
987
55
aasf
552
18278 blu
ttry
"""
```

And I need extract exactly this strings:

```
string1 = 
"""
1538 a
123
skua456
789
5
g
15563 blu55g
"""
```

```
string2 = """
16453 a
789
5
16524 blu
"""
```

```
string3 = 
"""
1734 a
987
987
55
aasf
552
18278 blu
"""
```

I have tried a lot of types: re.findall, re.search, re.match. But I never geted the result expected.

For eg: this code bellow print all string:

```
re.split(r"a(.*)blu", a)[0]
```

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'(?m)^.*a(?:\n.*)*?\n.*blu.*', text)` - https://regex101.com/r/vHsJKD/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a regex for this, you may get lines between lines containing `a` and `blu`:

```py
text = "1538 a\n123\nskua456\n789\n5\ng\n15563 blu55g\nb\n456\n16453 a\n789\n5\n16524 blu\ng\n55\n1734 a\n987\n987\n55\naasf\n552\n18278 blu\nttry"
f = False
result = []
block = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    if 'a' in line:
        f = True
    if f:
        block.append(line)
    if 'blu' in line and f:
        f = False
        result.append("\n".join(block))
        block = []

print(result)
# => ['1538 a\n123\nskua456\n789\n5\ng\n15563 blu55g', '16453 a\n789\n5\n16524 blu', '1734 a\n987\n987\n55\naasf\n552\n18278 blu']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DmLIDV).

With regex, you can use

```py
print( re.findall(r'(?m)^.*a(?s:.*?)blu.*', text) )
print( re.findall(r'(?m)^.*a(?:\n.*)*?\n.*blu.*', text) )
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/rwn050).

The [first regex](https://regex101.com/r/OjblSF/1) means:

- `(?m)^` - multiline mode on, so `^` matches any line start position
- `.*a` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then `a`
- `(?s:.*?)` - any zero or more chars including line break chars as few as possible
- `blu.*` - `blue` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

The [second regex](https://regex101.com/r/OjblSF/2) matches

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `.*a` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then `a`
- `(?:\n.*)*?` - zero or more lines, as few as possible
- `\n.*blu.*` - a newline, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, `blu` and any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.